# Ubuntu 20.04 touchpad not working on Lenovo Thinkbook

Tags: 20.04, touchpad

Ubuntu 20.04 touchpad not working on Lenovo Thinkbook.

I tried all the solutions on Ubuntu still not working.

`cat /proc/bus/input/devices`

I tried listing devices but its not showing input device like thinkpad.

Is that it has been 10 months and bug is not fixed?

Answer (score 1):

This is bad ubuntu code that can't work with the latest bios versions, but they won't tell you that here. You will be told that your equipment is bad and that you should think for yourself what to do. I ordered a new keyboard with a built-in touchpad before I found the answer to this question myself. And if you flash your BIOS to an older one, you will be told that it does not meet the security requirements.